# Displaying initial values in DJango CRUD application in a form

Tags: python, html, django

I have created an add/update form in Django Crud application. The Model for data is like this:

```
class Proposal(models.Model):
    org = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    recdate = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    subdate = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=20)
```

and in views.py I have following code for add and update:

**ADD**

```
def proposal_create(request, template_name='proposal/proposal_form.html'):
    form = ProposalForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return redirect('list')
    return render(request, template_name, {'form':form})
```

**UPDATE**

```
def proposal_update(request, pk, template_name='proposal/proposal_form.html'):
    server = get_object_or_404(Proposal, pk=pk)
    form = ProposalForm(request.POST or None, instance=server)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return redirect('list')
    return render(request, template_name, {'form':form})
```

AND finally I have in my template I have forms.py which is like this:

```
<div align="center" style=" margin-top: 150; padding-top: 30; padding-bottom: 20; text-align: right; border-style: double;  width: 50%; float: center; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; background-color: grey; color: black; border-color: white; border-width: 5px; box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888888;">
<form method="post">{% csrf_token %}
<div align="center" style="margin-right: auto; margin-left: auto; align-content: center; width: 80%; vertical-align: middle;">
<table class="table table-bordered">
    <tr>
        <td valign="middle" width="30%"><label for="{{ form.org.id_for_label }}">Organization:</label></td>
        <td valign="middle" width="70%"><input type="text" name="org" class="form-control" form="{form.org}"></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td valign="middle" width="30%"><label for="{{ form.country.id_for_label }}">Country:</label></td>
        <td valign="middle" width="70%"><input type="text" name="org" class="form-control" form="{form.country}"></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td valign="middle" width="30%"><label for="{{ form.recdate.id_for_label }}">Received Date:</label></td>
        <td valign="middle" width="70%"><input type="Date" name="org" class="form-control" form="{form.recdate}"></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td valign="middle" width="30%"><label for="{{ form.subdate.id_for_label }}">Submission Deadline:</label></td>
        <td valign="middle" width="70%"><input type="Date" name="org" class="form-control" form="{form.subdate}"></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td valign="middle" width="30%"><label for="{{ form.status.id_for_label }}">Status:</label></td>
        <td valign="middle" width="70%"><input list="status" name="org" class="form-control" form="{form.status}">
        <datalist id="status">
            <option value="Pending">Pending</option>
            <option value="Submitted">Submitted</option>
        </datalist>
        </td>
     </tr>
    <tr></tr>

</table>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" style="background-color: white; color: black;" />
    <a href="/list" style="background-color: white; color: black;"><input type="button" value="Cancel" /></a>
</div>

</form>
```

The problem I am facing is this:

** for add the form works perfectly fine, but for edit the form fields are not populated with initial data if I use single curly brackets like this:**

```
<td valign="middle" width="70%"><input type="text" name="org" class="form-control" form="{form.org}"></td>
```

**the initial data gets displayed if I use double curly brackets like thes:**

```
<td valign="middle" width="70%"><input type="text" name="org" class="form-control" form="{{form.org}}"></td>
```

But then "> after the ending double curly brackets gets displayed after the form field.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of putting form fields in input tags I was able to achieve it by using django-widget-tweaks so that I could add CSS classes to the fields.

So instead of writing code like this:

```
<td valign="middle" width="70%"><input type="text" name="org" class="form-control" form="{form.org}"></td>
```

I could just write like this:
    {{form.org|attr:"type:text"|add_class:"form-control"}}

All I had to do is download and install django-widget-tweaks

```
python -m pip install django-widget-tweaks
```

Further information can be found here: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-widget-tweaks